# Can't find nor use System.Web.Services.dll

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use some code (C#, I think with .NET) I found on the Internet but my Visual Studio 2017 says it can't find `System.Web.Services.dll`.

Effectively, I went to the reference tab and I didn't find it. Also, I check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform\6.1.9\ref\uap10.0.15138` but nothing I could found.

It's my first time using these technologies (C#, .NET and UWP...) so I am not sure if I'm missing some steps in order to import and use that `dll`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `System.Web.Services` is obsolete. It contains classes used to create the old ASMX web services. They were replaced by WCF in 2008 and can't be used in a UWP application anyway. What are you trying to do and why do you think you need that dll?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I was trying to make an application for the AFIP (AKA: Argentinian taxes) and it shows a C# example of a WSAA which uses that code. It's a pity that all the AFIP documentation is really outdated.

Comment: One can safely assume that the *tax service's* documentation will *never* be appropriate or even adequate when it comes to programming. Their job is to collect taxes, not write tutorials.

Comment: If you want to *call* a web service, you only need to create a proxy from its WSDL descriptions. In most types of applications you can do that by selecting `Add Service Reference` and passing the URL of the service or its WSDL description. This will work with any standards-compliant SOAP service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add Web Reference for UWP in VS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498209/how-to-add-web-reference-for-uwp-in-vs-2015)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm sorry, I am not a software developer, just I am trying to make a program for my parent's shop. So I order to use WSAA it's not mandatory the usage of `System.Web.Services`?

Comment: Don't create a UWP application then. UWP makes sense when you want to deploy the application through Microsoft's App Store. Create a WPF application instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you may be right. But if someday I want to share it because it works fine would I be able to deploy it on the App Store?. So returning to my previous question if you don't mind: Is possible to use WSAA (web service authentification and authorizing) without using System.Web.Services or it's mandatory? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the reference. You must:

1. Right click on "References" -> "Add Reference"
2. Navigate to the "Assemblies" -> "Framework" section
3. Look for the "System.Web.Services" assembly and check it.

Check screenshot for more details.

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/624Ca.png)

Comment: +1 because your idea works... but sadly on WPF. Do you know if it's possible to add the reference in UWP?